# Asp mvc: IControllerFactory.CreateController and threads

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm implementing a custom IControllerFactory to create my asp.net mvc controllers.
In this factory's CreateController method, I'm relying on the fact that the thread
that creates the controller, is unique; meaning no other Controller is created on that thread before ReleaseController is called.

Now, under heavy load testing, I'm running into issues.
Say that I have created Controllers on threads 1,2,3, it appears that a new 
Controller is being created on thread 1, before the first one has called 
IControllerFactory.ReleaseController.

Is this an expected behavior?
Each request to the controller is handled on a separate thread, right?
How comes the same thread is being reused for a different request, before IControllerFactory's ReleaseController method is called?

Thanks for your time,
Koen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In this factory's CreateController method, I'm relying on the fact
>   that the thread that creates the controller, is unique; meaning no
>   other Controller is created on that thread before ReleaseController is
>   called.

You absolutely cannot rely on such behavior. There's nothing guaranteeing you that. Things could get even worse if you use asynchronous controllers.

> Is this an expected behavior?

Yes.

> Each request to the controller is handled on a separate thread, right?

No.

> How comes the same thread is being reused for a different request,
>   before IControllerFactory's ReleaseController method is called?

ASP.NET uses a thread pool to service requests. So for example a thread is drawn from this pool to service the request and later this thread is returned to the pool for reuse. So you could perfectly fine have the same thread execute the controller code for two completely separate requests.

You should absolutely never rely in an ASP.NET application on threads. If you want to store some per-request specific information you should use the HttpContext storage, not threads. Forget about threads in an ASP.NET application if you want to be safe.

Comment: Thanks,

Let me clarify a bit.
Supposing I'm not using asynchronous controller, the following is a correct statement, right?
"Each request is handled by a single thread and a single thread does not handle multiple requests at the same time".

I'm not looking to store per-request information, but to use resources like an Entity Framework ObjectContext on a per request scope basis.

So I was initializing these resources in the CreateController method and disposing them in the ReleaseController methods.

Koen

Comment: Furthermore,

The issue only seems to occur when using
the ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(IControllerFactory) method, not when using the ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(Type) method.

Comment: If you want to store per-request information the correct place to do so is the HttpContext - the only safe place to persist this kind of information. I cannot provide you with any guarantees about what gets executed on which thread. That's an implementation detail that you cannot rely upon. Not to mention that those implementations might change in the future with the introduction of tasks and so on. So once again, if you want guarantees you should use HttpContext.